# Can't execute java commands (java -version, java -jar)

Tags: java, jar

`echo %JAVA_HOME%` produces `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151` so at least this seems to be correct. 
When I am running `java -version` I am getting these two errors: 
`Error: could not find java.dll`
`Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`

Obviously I am not able to run a `.jar`-file as well.

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME should point to jdk and not jre..some thing like this "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92"

Comment: Tried that out: `echo %JAVA_HOME%` returns `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`.
`java -version` still doesn't work

Comment: It appears your Java installation is corrupt.  Delete the entire directory, and re-install it.  (This doesn’t happen normally;  some person or program must have done it, but regardless, it’s easier to reinstall than to try to repair it, especially since you have nothing to lose by doing so.)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that tomorrow morning. Do I need to confige `JAVA_HOME` and the system variables again? Or will it do that itself?